# Creating a dictionary of booleans from a list of variables

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I'm trying to create a dictionary of booleans using the variables of an expression. So if expression 1 had the variables `{x,y,z}` I can create a dictionary that when produced would return something like `{'x': True, 'y': True, 'z': True}, {'x': False, 'y': True, 'z': True} ... etc`

But I'm really struggling as this function needs to work with sets / (maybe I should make them into lists?) of different variables, so for just `{x}` the dictionary would be `{'x' : True}, {'x' : False}`

So far I'm trying a code along the lines of

```
def dicx(self):
    for i in self.vars():
        dicxow = { i : True for i in self.vars() }
        dicxow1 = dicxow.copy()
        dicxow1 = {i : False for i in self.vars() }
        return dicxow, dicxow1
```

where `self.vars()` returns all the variables in an expression.

I'm so lost as to where to go from this as I can't work out how to change just one part of the dictionary for each different variable and so any hints would be appreciated. My task included the use of classes so I am using classes to do this (I'm not sure if that makes a difference here).

Edit:

Ok sorry, so I just want to create a dictionary with every possible combination of True and False for x amount of variables but I am struggling to do so. self.vars() returns a set of variables from an expression e.g. {x,y} and from that I want to create a function to generate every combination of True and False for x and y.

Comment: your task doesn't make sense? when do you want it to be False, and when do you want it to be True?, what you are doing is just making a similar dictionaries with opposite values...

Comment: self.vars() is a dictionary, right? You want to use the keys or the values? I am not fully understanding your question.

Comment: why the outer loop? `for i in self.vars():`. Also this is useless `dicxow1 = dicxow.copy()` as you're overwriting the ref the next line

Comment: Sorry - I have just edited to clarify what I'm trying to do. I tried at first with the outer loop and not having the "for i in self.vars()" in the dicxow but it wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does something close to what you want. To get all the combinations of `True` and `False` for **n** variables, it just produces all the integer values from 0 to 2<sup>**n**</sup>-1. I put everything in a dummy `class` to make it more like your assignment.

```
from pprint import pprint

class Expression:

    def __init__(self, *variables):
        self.variables = variables

    def vars(self):
        return self.variables

    def dicx(self):
        def bools(bit_string):  # Helper function
            """ Convert string of binary chars to list of corresponding booleans. """
            return [ch == '1' for ch in bit_string]

        n = len(self.vars())
        vals = list(range(2**n))
        bits = [format(v, f'0{n}b') for v in vals]
        return [dict(zip(self.vars(), bools(combo))) for combo in bits]


instance = Expression('x', 'y', 'z')
pprint(instance.dicx(), sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
[{'x': False, 'y': False, 'z': False},
 {'x': False, 'y': False, 'z': True},
 {'x': False, 'y': True, 'z': False},
 {'x': False, 'y': True, 'z': True},
 {'x': True, 'y': False, 'z': False},
 {'x': True, 'y': False, 'z': True},
 {'x': True, 'y': True, 'z': False},
 {'x': True, 'y': True, 'z': True}]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Just one question, what does the format() do here? I've not seen it before

Comment: [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) is a built-in function that converts values into strings in a controlled way. Here it's being to used to convert integer values into strings of binary digits of a certain length (`n`). i.e. `2` → `'010'`